# Share files between azure pipeline Jobs

Tags: azure-pipelines, jobs, agent, artifacts

In the documentation of the Azure pipelines, I read that:

> Each agent can run only one job at a time. To run multiple jobs in
>   parallel you must configure multiple agents.
>
> When you run a pipeline on a self-hosted agent, by default, none of
>   the sub-directories are cleaned in between two consecutive runs. As a
>   result, you can do incremental builds and deployments, provided that
>   tasks are implemented to make use of that. You can override this
>   behavior using the workspace setting on the job.
>
> Pipeline artifacts provide a way to share files between stages in a
>   pipeline or between different pipelines. They are typically the output
>   of a build process that needs to be consumed by another job or be
>   deployed.

As a beginner, after reading this, I have some doubts:

1. If I have 2 jobs (2nd job runs after the 1st) in an azure-pipelines.yaml, will both the jobs run in the same agent? Do different jobs in the same pipeline share the same workspace that can be referenced via the variable `Pipeline.Workspace`? ( It is clear that in the parallel job run case, it would need multiple agents).
2. The 1st job generates some files in one step. Is it possible to consume those files in 2nd job without using artifacts (normally using artifacts, 1st job publishes the artifact and 2nd job downloads it)?

Can some please help me to clear these doubts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If I have 2 jobs (2nd job runs after the 1st) in an
>   azure-pipelines.yaml, will both the jobs run in the same agent?

Strictly speaking, NO, neither `UI` nor `YAML` can achieve that.

As what you saw from the document: *Each agent can run only one job at a time.* Our design logic is, in theory, one job is an **independent** running individual, the communication between different jobs **requires** the use of "middleware", like `variable`, `artifact` and etc.

> Do different jobs in the same pipeline share the same workspace that
>   can be referenced via the variable Pipeline.Workspace?

**Sample1:**

I have 2 jobs in one pipeline, one is `job01` and another is `job02`.

In `job01`, I create one json file into `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` names `project.json`:

[image]

In job02, print the files list that under path `$(Pipeline.Workspace)`:

[image]

You can see, the second job could not access the output directory of first job.

---

**BUT**, there has one special case, that the pipeline is running with self-agent pool and only one agent exists in that pool.

At this time, they can run on same agent since there is only one agent in the pool. And, if you do not manually perform `clean` operation in the job definition, files can be shared between jobs in this special scenario because they are using a constant local path.

**Sample2:**

*Same with previous sample, but this time change the running pool to the one that only contain 1 agent.*

[image]

> The 1st job generates some files in one step. Is it possible to
>   consume those files in 2nd job without using artifacts

*I think my above special case description and `sample2` has answer this.*

Yes, it possible. You can refer to that to achieve this demand. But, mostly we recommend you use artifacts to pass files between jobs.

Comment: Thank you so much! You clearly explained everything.

Answer (score 0):

If your agents are on-prem, you can use a network share. Add a pipeline variable:

```
SharePath = \\machine\automation\$(Build.BuildID)
```

Make sure the account running the agent has r/w access to the share. JobN can write or robocopy whatever it needs to the share, JobN+1 can read or copy it to continue work. On success, a final job should clean up any content from the share that doesn't need to hang around forever.

Also, if JobN+1 fails because the output from JobN was bad, (*you of course will be fixing JobN, but in the meantime*) you can fix the share output by hand and re-run JobN+1.